# how to disable element attribute on specific screen width in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

in my navbar i have Event drop down menu(see print screen). so if i hover mouse on it, dropdown menu will appear. with help of `dropdown-toggle disabled` if i click on Event link i will go to events page. but i want to remove this disabled attribute when screen width less then 768px. i know, i can do it with js, but is there way to do it only with bootstrap? in code it looks like this

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{lang}/events">Events
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

so when screen width less then 768px i want to remove disabled attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only pure-bootstrap, no-JS solution I can think of is to duplicate the element in the code, with the disabled version having class `hidden-xs` and the non-disabled version having class `visible-xs-inline-block` (or `visible-xs-block`, maybe? not sure which display property you want).

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle disabled hidden-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{lang}/events">Events
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
<a class="dropdown-toggle visible-xs-inline-block" data-toggle="dropdown" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{lang}/events">Events
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Comment: Yes, something like this (like you say a combo of `visible-*` or `hidden-*` classes) but urgh, double the markup. Possibly add an extra non-Bootstrap class along with `.disabled` and override / target with a media query...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hidden tags to hide on certain screen sizes: [Visibility Breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

So for <768 you would add the classes `.hidden-xs` and `.hidden-sm`

Comment: The OP only wants to remove the behaviour that `disabled` adds to the anchor - not hide it completely. Otherwise what you say is valid.